# How to have a button open/close a section of a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

I needed to have a "form" that can be filled out, with an "advanced' section, so I opted to use a UITableViewController. I had 3 sections. The first one has three cells, Label + textboxes. The second, I wanted to be the "advanced" optional search features. I wanted to have a button that if you tap, it makes the "section 2" appear or disappear to allow the users to select more features. And finally, the third section is just one cell, where I made the button full that says "SUBMIT". So, 1) is this the right approach, and 2) how can I achieve this open/close?

Comment: Please research regarding Collapse and Expand UITableViewCell. You will get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is good. AppCoda has [a great tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/) on doing just that.

Good luck!